# Module Forms - Store Value of addField to a Variable

Tags: forms, magento, module

I have something like in my custom module:

```
$fieldset->addField('orderinfo', 'link', array(
      'label'     => Mage::helper('web')->__('Order Info'),
      'style'   => "",
      'href' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $order_id)),
      'value'  => 'Magento Blog',
      'after_element_html' => '',
    ));
```

And as you can see from the code, I am trying to link that field to the Order Tab in the back-end. I'm having trouble getting the ID though. I'm planning to just save the Order ID in the database, and then using the addField I could have the correct url.

But how can I save an addField value to a variable?

I want to store the value in "$order_id".

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure in which context you are using this fieldset but if it is used for example for creating or editing object you can try something like that:

In controller:

```
public function editAction()
{
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $model  = Mage::getModel('module/model')->load($id);
    Mage::register('model_name', $model);
}
```

and then in the block:

```
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    $model = Mage::registry('model_name');

    // add fieldset to form

    $fieldset->addField('orderinfo', 'link', array(
      'label'     => Mage::helper('web')->__('Order Info'),
      'style'   => "",
      'href' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $model->getOrderId())),
      'value'  => 'Magento Blog',
      'after_element_html' => '',
    ));

    //rest of the elements
}
```

Answering my own post again. (src: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/682/module-forms-store-value-of-addfield-to-a-variable)